# How to compare if a set of items exists in another set of items

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, cocoa, nsset

I have two arrays.

At first, I was comparing the counts of both of the `arrays` than putting them in an `NSSet` to check if they contained keywords. If that `bool` returned true, then I added them to `finalArray`.

```
NSInteger int1 = inputArray.count;
NSInteger int2 = databaseArray.count;

if (int1 == int2) {   
    NSArray *array = [inputArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY %@ contains[cd] self", databaseArray]];
    NSSet *set1 = [NSSet inputArray];
    NSSet *set2 = [NSSet setWithArray:array];   

    if([set1 isEqualtoSet:set2]) {
```

Consider the following case:

```
inputArray = @"John", @"Kyle" 
dataBaseArray[0] =  @"third john Stewart", @"second kyle braflowski"
```

In this example, my code would add the item to my `finalArray` because `inputArray.count == dataBasesArray.count` (i.e. 2 == 2) and set 2 contains "john" and "kyle."

But it turns out my algorithm is wrong for my purposes.

Consider the following example (written in pseudocode):

```
inputArray = @"John" , @"Kyle", @"George", @"Mary"
dataBaseArray[0] =  @"third john Stewart", @"second kyle braflowski"
databaseArray[3] = @"First Mary Steps", @"fourth kyle lomorik",@"second George steps"
```

I need my algorithm to add both of these items from the `databaseArray` to the `finalArray` since I have all the keys from `inputArray` in both `databaseArray[0]` (john,Kyle) and `databaseArray[3]` (george,kyle,mary).

How can I get the proper solution in the case where inputArray.count > databaseArray.count?

a new example

```
input array = (@"rice", @"chicken",@"tomato",@"egg")
```

and lets say i got 2 item from my database that one has 
`(@"100 gr rice",@"250 gr chicken")` and the other `(@"250 gr chicken",@"4 eggs",@"3 tomato@")`

with this current input. i need to able to add both of the items from my database to a finalArray to show it on a tableView.

Comment: Start by changing `NSInteger *` to just `NSInteger`. Those shouldn't be pointers.

Comment: @rmaddy done.But that wasn't the source of the problem :)

Comment: @rmaddy do you have any idea or suggestions.I tried every idea i had and it drives me crazy

Comment: Honestly, I really don't understand your question and the formatting makes it hard to read. You will probably get more help if you can clarify the question and fix the formatting.

Comment: @rmaddy i tried to clarify but not sure i made it.Can i help you where you couldn't understand?

Comment: @rmaddy guess i m on my own

Comment: Would the `NSSet` method `isSubsetOfSet:` do what you want? The docs for it are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000143-CHDBAEFB).

Comment: It would help if you would clarify your question in terms of what you are trying to achieve - at the moment you have an XY problem - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem.  It seems that you are trying to produce an array that contains items from `dataBaseArray` that contain any of the words in the `inputArray` ? Your examples are confusing because one of them shows an array with dimension 0 that contains two elements?  What are the sizes of the inputs - a few elements, a dozen, a hundred, a thousand?

Comment: @user1118321 no it doesn't thats the first thing i tried

Comment: @Paulw11 . yea thats my bad of writing bad syntax here. 

yes . If all elements from input array exist in the database array, i want to add that object to my finalArray.The max size for both arrays are about 10.

Comment: Still not clear.  Given your first example, do you want final array to contain "john" and "Kyle" or "third john stewart" and "second kyle braflovski" ?  What if the input array was "john" and "peter" - should the output be "john" or "third john steward"?

Comment: @Paulw11 added one more example. And for your example. I want my final array to contain third john steward and second kyle braflovski but i can already manage to do that.For the same example if the user gives input john and peter since there is no peter in the database array i shouldn't add it

Comment: @Paulw11 any idea now?

Comment: I am working on an answer, but to clarify, each element in your `databaseArray` is an array of NSStrings?

Comment: @Paulw11 i have an array of dictionaries
 recipe = arrayOfDictionaries[i]; 
NSString *recipeIngString = recipe[@"recipeIngredients"]; i take ingredients

and put it the content to an array 

 NSArray *recipeIngredientsArray = [recipeIngString componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@","]]; 

so yea my databaseArray is an array of NSStrings

thank you so much for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, but I am assuming that each element in your `databaseArray` is an array of NSStrings.

The following method pulls each line in each element in `databaseArray` apart into separate words and verifies that at least one word from each line in the supplies list.

```
- (NSArray *) intersectCandidates:(NSArray *)candidates withSupplies:(NSArray *)supplies
{

   NSMutableArray *output=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

   NSSet *suppliesSet=[NSSet setWithArray:supplies];

   for (NSArray *candidateLines in candidates) {
     int count=0;
     for (NSString *candidateLine in candidateLines) {
        NSArray *wordArray=[candidateLine componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];
        for (NSString *word in wordArray) {
            if ([suppliesSet contains:word]) {
               ++count;
               break;
            }
        }
     }
     if (count == [candidateLines count]) {   // We matched one word from each line
           [output addObject:candidateLines];
     }       

   }

   return [NSArray arrayWithArray:output];   // Return a non-mutable copy
}
```

Because of the aforementioned XY problem, I am not sure that this is the most efficient way of solving your actual problem.

Comment: i think that would work but i m having this error [__NSCFString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1096cbe40
don't know why

Comment: It means that a method was invoked on a string, but the string doesn't support that method. What line is the exception occurring on?

Comment: NSSet *suppliesSet=[NSSet setWithArray:supplies];
    
  here

Comment: So supplies is a string, not an array of strings. You should pass an array of string where each string is one ingredient

Comment: for (NSString *candidateLine in candidateLines) { now this is where i get the same error.

i hardcorded 2 arrays to see if it will work with arrays of strings.

Comment: ok i understood the errors which you made in 3 places. Its currently not working but i think i can go from what you left

Comment: okay it took me a while but can made it work with your code so thnx

Answer (score 0):

I read your question a few times, and I honestly have no idea what you're asking.  According to the title, you want to "compare if a set of items exists in another set of items"  You can do that with a NSMutableSet:

```
NSMutableSet * set1 = ...;
NSMutableSet * set2 = ...;

[set1 intersectsWithSet:set2];

// set 1 now contains all the objects that the two sets have in common
NSLog(@"ObjectsInCommon: %@", set1);
```